# Inserting multiple links to option tag and choosing a specific image from chosen link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image

I am trying to display an specific image from different types of links using dropdown option.

**What I want to do:**
I have 6 different types of links these links needs to be added into dropdown option. After the desired **Option** (category) is chosen from dropdown, **Textbox** will appear in the textbox I want to write specific image name for example **1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, etc...** then desired image will be displayed.

```
www.example.com/Category-1/images/8.png
www.example.com/Category-2/Imagess/3.png
www.example.com/Category-3/Imagess/5.png
www.example.com/Category-4/images/4.png
www.example.com/Category-5/images/7.png
www.example.com/Category-6/images/11.png
```

I need a some sort of JavaScript or jQuery Function to do this. I did some research with no luck.

If it's possible to create some type of function that performs above I would really appreciate that.

The code below shows images from only specific URL.

**What I've tried:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4"><br>
  <span>Please Choose desired Category</span>
  <select class="SelectID">
    <option value="1">Category-1</option>
    <option value="2">Category-2</option>
    <option value="3">Category-3</option>
    <option value="4">Category-4</option>
    <option value="5">Category-5</option>
    <option value="6">Category-6</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#btnShow').click(function() {
      $("#imgMain").attr("src", $("#txtImageUrl").val());
      $('#imgMain').width(200); // Units are assumed to be pixels
      $('#imgMain').height(200);

    })
  })
</script><br>
<div>
  Img URL:<input type="text" id="txtImageUrl" />
  <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show Image" />
</div>
<br />
<img id="imgMain" />
```

Comment: _"Textbox will appear in the textbox I want to write specific **image name** for example 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, etc"_ Do you mean image URL or image name?

Comment: Its not about "Luck", you need to work more on your code...

Comment: Hello! thanks for replying I know, I need some function that contains links and does everything. I've done so many research with no luck I haven't created any function. I'm kind of new in JavaScript (learning) So maybe my question is not professional.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are dynamically building the image URL based on the form. I've added some rudimentary validation also to point you in the right direction.

Please make sure to set your base URL and path correctly.

```js
$(function() {
  var category, folder, url;
  $(".SelectID").change(function() {
    category = $(this).val();
  });
  $("#folder").change(function() {
    folder = $(this).val();
  });
  $("#txtImageUrl").keyup(function() {
    url = $(this).val();
  });
  $('#btnShow').click(function() {
    if (category && folder && url) {
      $("#imgMain").attr("src", 'http://www.example.com/Category-' + category + '/' + folder + '/' + url + '.png').width(200).height(200);
    } else {
      console.log('You must choose a category and folder and set a url.');
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4"><br>
  <span>Please Choose desired Category</span>
  <select class="SelectID">
    <option value="3">Category-1</option>
    <option value="4">Category-2</option>
    <option value="5">Category-3</option>
    <option value="6">Category-4</option>
    <option value="7">Category-5</option>
    <option value="8">Category-6</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"><br>
  <span>Please Choose desired Folder</span>
  <select id="folder">
    <option value="images">images</option>
    <option value="Images">Images</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  Img URL:<input type="text" id="txtImageUrl" />
  <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show Image" />
</div>
<br />
<img id="imgMain" />
```

Comment: Hello Sir! Thanks for answering! I have a problem how do I make IF ELSE Statement for directory name 

 www.example.com/Category-1/images/8.png
www.example.com/Category-2/Images/3.png images and Images are two different directories

Comment: Just follow the same patter as before! I have updated the answer for you - but please don't keep adding to the question. If you are happy with this then please accept the answer.